# How to do this kind of sorting (in MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, vector

I have a square matrix and I want to get a 2 by n matrix that will have indices of matrix in a sorted order. For example, I want to get from this matrix

0 0 0

1 0 0

2 3 0

something like this

[3 2; 3 1; 2 1] ....

(3,2) being the indices of the biggest element in the matrix, (3,1) the second biggest and so on. It would be good if it could ignore zeros (or NaN-s instead of zeros).

Additional information about the matrix: it is positive, but not necessarily 3 by 3, diagonal elements and every element above the diagonal is either 0 or NaN (a side question, which is processed faster, NaNs or 0s?)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This considers only non-zero elements:

```
[ii, jj, aa] = find(A);
[~, kk] = sort(aa, 'descend');
result = [ii(kk) jj(kk)];
```

Comment: Note that `find` treats `Nan` elements as a non-zero, so they will be included in the result.

Comment: @beaker It is my understanding that the OP can choose to set non-significant values to either `0` or `NaN`. With my approach it would have to be `0`, as you say. If it's `NaN`, doing `A(isnan(A)) = 0` initially would suffice

Comment: Exactly, just pointing it out so the OP knows to use `0` rather than `NaN`.

Comment: @beaker I thought that was clear from the statement "_This considers only non-zero elements_" in my answer. But you're right: better to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems really elegant. I can simply use 0-s instead of Nans if because turning nans into zeros would use up more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix is in `A`, you need to use the `ind2sub` function,

Edited to remove zero indices

```
[Ap, i] = sort(A(:), 'descend');
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), i);
orderedPairs = [r,c];
orderedPairsSansZeros = orderedPairs(Ap ~= 0, :);
```

Comment: I voted you +1, but you should refine your answer, in the example he doesn't take into the account the 0s.

Answer (score 0):

This following should work. The matrix `sortix` is what you're looking for. I've replaced a zero in your (1,3) element with NaN so you can see that NaN's don't show up in your final ordered matrix.

```
matrix = [0, 0, NaN;
          1, 3, 0;
          2, 3, 0];

new_matrix = matrix;

%new_matrix(new_matrix(:)==0) = NaN; % uncomment to get rid of zeros

saveix = 1;

for i=1:length(matrix(:))
    [maxVal, maxIndex] = max(new_matrix(:));

    allMax = ismember(new_matrix, maxVal);
    idx = find(allMax);

    for ix=1:length(idx)
        [sortix(saveix, 1), sortix(saveix, 2)] = ind2sub(size(matrix), ...
            idx(ix));
        saveix = saveix + 1;
    end

    new_matrix(idx) = NaN;
end
```